# How to configure database link over JPA/Hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to use a database link to access another db using JPA/Hibernate, I know that a possible solution is to use 2 dataSources, but the requirement here is to use the defined dblink.

here is how i did proceed :

I configured my entity as in the current example:

```
@Table(name = "USER@DBLINK")
public class User{
...
}
```

define my repository

```
@Repository
public interface userDao extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select userfrom  User where status = :status")
    Iterable<User> find(@Param("status") String status);
}
```

I tried also by defining a synonymous, but I keep getting:
oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

**Knowing that from SqlDeveloper running the same query I have on my repository, works fine:**

```
SELECT * FROM USER@DBLINK;
```

Comment: Please show the synonym creation statement

Comment: create public SYNONYM MY_USER for USER@DBLINK;

Comment: is "USER" the name of the table?

Comment: Yes the issue is not with the db_link. Is more how to configure this with Hibernate.

Comment: You may define a view pointing to the remote table. Check if the DB Link user has the select grant on the table.